# Failure to upload files on Glitch using Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a Glitch project and I want to upload files to it via user input. I am using express-fileupload and I followed the sample code from their docs to upload a file, but I keep getting an error. I think it might have to do with the directory I am using to move the file to. I have tried using '/app/views/uploads' and 'uploads/' as well as '/assets' (I used assets.js to do so) and I haven't been able to store the file. Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fileUpload= require('express-fileupload');
var app = express();

var assets = require("./assets");
app.use("/assets", assets);

app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(fileUpload());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  response.render('index');
});


app.get('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
  res.render('upload');
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  var sample= req.files.sample;

   sample.mv('/assets', function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('SERVER STARTED ON PORT ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

The file is received succesfully, so the file not being there is not why I get errors.

I normally get this as the error:

```
{"errno":-13,"code":"EACCES","syscall":"open","path":"/assets"}
```

If you know where to upload the files to, please let me know. Any help would be very appreciated!